# Extract number from string value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parsing, numbers, data-extraction

I have a string that always come into this format:

"TM" + multiple Leading 0 + Number + Non-Number Character + Alphanumeric.

For example: TM000013452S20548, PB000013452S3DVSF.

How do I parse (in C# code) the varchar value to get the "Number" (13452) in this case?

Comment: iterate every character of the string to see if it is a number.. append to str.. then finally parse it.

Comment: `int number = int.Parse(string.Concat(input.SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c) || c == '0').TakeWhile(char.IsDigit)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RegualarExpressions:

```
(?:TM|PB)0{0,}(\d+)
```

Like this:

```
string input = "For example: TM000013452S20548, PB000013452S3DVSF.";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?:TM|PB)0{0,}(\d+)");
foreach(Match m in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value));
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7OcEFR)

Comment: This wouldn't work as the OP specified that input can be PB000013452S3DVSF as well. Please make sure to fix the Regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq:

```
var number = new String(
       yourString.Skip(2)
                 .SkipWhile(s => s == '0')
                 .TakeWhile(s => Char.IsDigit(s))
                 .ToArray()
          );
```

Comment: or you could replace `new String` with `string.Concat` and then you can remove the `.ToArray()` (not sure that makes any difference, though)

Answer (score 0):

If all the fields are fixed width, and all you care about is the first integer, then it's pretty easy; just use `string.Substring` to extract the part you care about and then parse it.

Here's how to do the extract and parse (note that I use `int.TryParse` - you are parsing a possibly corrupted string):

```
private bool TryExtractFirstNumber(string input, out int result)
{
    var resultString = input.Substring(2, 9);
    return int.TryParse(resultString, out result);
}
```

You can call this like:

```
var inputs = new[]
{
    "TM000013452S20548",
    "PB000013452S3DVSF",
};
foreach (var inp in inputs)
{
    if (TryExtractFirstNumber(inp, out var result))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

The output from that is:

> 13452
>   13452

If the position of the *"Non-Number Character"* that you describe is not known, go looking for it:

```
private int FindIndexOfFirstNonNumeric(string toScan, int startIndex = 0)
{
    for (var index = startIndex; index < toScan.Length; ++index)
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(toScan[index]))
        {
            return index;
        }
    }

    return toScan.Length;
}
```

and then modify the `TryExtractFirstNumber` function to look for it:

```
private bool TryExtractFirstNumber(string input, out int result)
{
    var length = FindIndexOfFirstNonNumeric(input, 2) - 2;
    var resultString = input.Substring(2, length);
    return int.TryParse(resultString, out result);
}
```

It gives the same results.